# flutter, TextField how to use it?

Tags: flutter, textfield

How can I use the `TextField`?
I have try on `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget`, still does not work.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'demo'
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error code:

```
I/flutter (22662): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (22662): The following assertion was thrown building TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "demo"),
I/flutter (22662): dirty, state: _TextFieldState#c0899):
I/flutter (22662): No Material widget found.
I/flutter (22662): TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
I/flutter (22662): In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's
I/flutter (22662): material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget
I/flutter (22662): that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that
I/flutter (22662): there be a Material widget in the tree above them.
I/flutter (22662): To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains
I/flutter (22662): Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.
I/flutter (22662): The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was:
I/flutter (22662):   TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "demo"))
I/flutter (22662): The ancestors of this widget were:
I/flutter (22662):   Container
I/flutter (22662):   MyApp
I/flutter (22662):   [root]
```

Comment: Do let me know if the given solution didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp( // make your MyApp a MaterialApp
      home: MyApp()
    ),
  );
}
```

You need to use either `MaterialApp` or `WidgetsApp` as the root of your widget tree in order to use material widgets.

Also update your `build()` method to include `Scaffold`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'demo'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```